Question about tensor decomposition
Let $M$ a differentiable manifold and $x \in M$. We know that a $(p,k)$-tensor in $x$ is a multilinear map
$$t:\underbrace{T_x^*M \times T_x^*M \times \ldots \times T_x^*M}_{p} \times \underbrace{T_xM \times T_xM \times \ldots \times T_xM}_{k} \to \mathbb{R}$$
which decompose in the canonical basis associated to a chart $(U, \phi)$ in:
$$t=t_{i_1\ldots i_k}^{j_1\ldots j_p} \frac{\partial}{\partial x^{j_1}}\vert_x \otimes \frac{\partial}{\partial x^{j_2}}\vert_x \otimes\ldots\otimes\frac{\partial}{\partial x^{j_p}}\vert_x\otimes dx^{i_1}\vert_x \otimes \ldots\otimes dx^{i_k}\vert_x.$$
I understand that for any $r$ we have that $dx^{i_r}\vert_x$ "eats" vectors from $T_xM$ and return a real value (Because $T_{\phi(x)}\mathbb{R} \simeq \mathbb{R}$). But, how $\frac{\partial}{\partial x^{j_r}}\vert_x$ "eats" elements from $T_x^*M$? I really don't understand...

$(V^){}^ \cong V$. (This isomorphism is called natural and does not depend on any choice of basis or on a metric.) $dx^i$ and $\partial/\partial x^i$ are dual basis vectors, in both directions.

@TedShifrin I know that $dx^i(\partial/\partial x^k) = \delta_i^j$. But how I can calculate $\partial / \partial x^i (dx^j)$?

Did you read my last sentence?

Use the isomorphism $V\to V^{**}$ given by $v\mapsto ev_v$, where $ev_v(f)=f(v)$ is the evaluation map.

Ooh. So to the value $\partial / \partial x^i ( dx^j)$ is associated to $dx^j(\partial / \partial x^i) = \delta_i^j$. It's correct?

Not associated to. Equal to. :)

Oh. Oook. I understand now! Thanks you!
